# Excel VBA - Change cell value via another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, cell

So VBA is completely new to me. I come from a C# background. 
Currently creating an order form, whereby I can input the total amount I require of an object and then the price is calculated in a different cell.

However I also want the price to change based off amount thresholds for that object.

Say for example 0 - 100 will cost £2.50 so I expect the answer to be anywhere within that range is multiplied by 2.50. Meanwhile if the amount exceeds 100 and becomes 120 I want the object price to now reflect £2.30 and proceed to multiple the 120 by £2.30.

I've noticed a few tutorials on line but they don't exactly explain how I might be able to achieve the above. Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: This could be done with formulas. Do you have a table of each object with the price breakdown for quantities? Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52749254/edit) and post sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Non VBA Soluion

If you build a table with the bottom and upper thresholds for a price, you can simply use a `VLOOKUP` and return the **approximate** match.

In photo, `Column C` is the output from the equation that is shown in `Column D`

[image]

---

### VBA Solution

You can also use a simple `UDF`. Paste the code inside a `Module` and then you can call the function `PRICEINDX` from a cell just like any other equation. You can either manually type in a value like `PRICEINDX(164)` or select a cell that has the value to be tested like `PRICEINDX(A1)`

You can also set up more complex thresholds easily by using `Select Case`

```
Option Explicit

Public Function PRICEINDX(Target As Double) As Double

Dim ans As Double

Select Case Target
    Case 0 To 100
        ans = 2.5
    Case 101 To 200
        ans = 2.3
    Case 201 To 300
        ans = 2.1
    Case Is > 300
        ans = 2
End Select

PRICEINDX = ans

End Function
```

Comment: @ScottCraner typo call out dropped me. True. Didn't know that. Thanks as always.... That's just how I always set it up :0

Comment: With Vlookup one only needs the minimum, the maximum is superfluous.  But really just wanted to tease about the typo.